# PHP session. Passing input value from one to another page

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to pass input value  from one page to another using php session. Spent all evening trying to solve this issue, but no results. Willing you could help me.  Here's my php script:

```
   <?php 
    $dbc = mysqli_connect ('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'db') or die ('Error connecting');
    $lt = $_POST ['lt'];
    $lg = $_POST ['lg'];
    $loc= $_POST ['loc'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO locations (lt, lg, loc)".
    "VALUES ('$lt', '$lg', '$loc')";
    mysqli_query ($dbc, $query)
    or die ('Error querying');
    header('Location: http://localhost:8888/stream.php');
    mysqli_close ($dbc);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['cl'] = $_POST['loc'];
    ?>
```

And HTML, where taken value should be passed:

```
<li class="currentLocation">
     <input class="currentLocationField" name="currentLocationField" type="text" value="<?php      echo $_SESSION["cl"] ?>" />
</li>
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: you should be calling `session_start()` at the beginning of the page...

Comment: And be careful with your queries (since you're already using mysqli, why not using parametrized queries?)

Comment: Your code is **wide open** to SQL injection, and **you will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Use prepared/parameterized queries with PDO or similar to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: You should set your sessions _before_ redirecting...

Comment: you must call header() after initializing the session variable.

Comment: @DamienPirsy, Yeah, I'm aware of SQL incejctions. It's just a demo version. I've tried to put session_start() at the begining of the script and before header (). Still no results. Checked Page Source, but it's just an empty space inside value.

Answer (score 0):

Just reorder the last four lines and you should be good to go:

```
header('Location: http://localhost:8888/stream.php');
mysqli_close ($dbc);
session_start();
$_SESSION['cl'] = $_POST['loc'];
```

Into this:

```
session_start(); // even better to put this at the very top of the page
$_SESSION['cl'] = $_POST['loc'];
mysqli_close ($dbc);
header('Location: http://localhost:8888/stream.php');
```

And don't forget to turn on the sessions on your landing page as well.